# How do I sample real numbers?

Tags: r, sampling

Is it possible to sample real numbers with the `sample()` function? (I.e., sample from a continuous distribution, e.g. [1,10] so that when I sample I won't get an integer but a real number, e.g 5.467.)
If not, is there another function to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by sampling real numbers? Are there no bounds? You want to sample between -Inf and Inf?

Comment: Do you want to sample from a uniform distribution between two numbers? Maybe `runif` will help. It's not really feasible to sample from all possible real numbers (most of which would not easily fit in computer memory -- there are a lot of large numbers on the way to infinity). Perhaps you can be more clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you both. What I am trying to do is to sample from a continuous distribution, e.g. [1,10] so that when I sample I won't get an integer but a real number, e.g 5.467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `sample` is to... well sample, uniformly or not, with replacement or not, from a finite set.

If you want a sample from another kind of distribution, it depends on the distribution, and there are many functions in R to achieve that. The most common are `runif` (uniform distribution on a bounded interval) and `rnorm` (the normal distribution).

See [`?sample`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sample.html) and [`?Distributions`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Distributions.html) in the documentation. A more comprehensive list can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html).

For instance:

Uniform sample with replacement, from {1, 2, 3, 4}:

```
> sample(1:4, 10, replace=T)
 [1] 3 1 4 1 2 1 1 3 4 3
```

Uniform sample from [0, 1]:

```
> runif(10)
 [1] 0.6529710 0.1977511 0.7946746 0.6351793 0.9518663
     0.9356524 0.2945506 0.4623502 0.8198065 0.8516961
```

Normal sample with mean 0 and variance 1:

```
> rnorm(10)
 [1] -1.13195127  0.43434313 -0.44183752  0.13632993  0.75902968  
      0.76079877  0.37919727  0.41350485  0.76233633  0.09400158
```

These functions can take parameters: `runif(n, a, b)` yields `n` samples from the interval [a, b] for instance.